# Android RelativeLayout and equal alignment

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a table row setup using relative layout. It has 2 TextView both of which I want to have equal spacing and left aligned text. See current setup below. This has one textview aligned left and another right. When I change to align both to left content overlaps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dip">
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/displayLabel"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/row_image"
         android:text="adasd"
         android:textSize="18sp" />    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="adasd"    
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a job for weighted LinearLayout - display two equaly-sized text views:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dip">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/displayLabel"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:text="adasd"
         android:textSize="18sp" 
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="adasd"    
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in emulator it will looks like:
[image: screenshot]

Note the `layout_weight` attribute in both text views and zero `layout_width`. Basically it means that the views will get additional amount of free space proportional to specified weight. So for equivalent weights these views will be of identical width.

See [layout guide on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using following for displayValue TextView instead of alignParentRight?

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/displayLabel"
```

Then give some left margin.